# Merge duplicates into one row and sum up values using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that hows the following rows...

```
ID     | TITLE   |   ARTIST    |   ADDED               |  HITS | HITS THIS WEEK
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7505   | Track 2 |   Artist 1  |   2009-08-24 10:32:41 |  1539 |  2
7483   | Track 2 |   Artist 1  |   2009-08-23 16:58:35 |  1450 |  3
7324   | Track 1 |   Artist 1  |   2009-08-14 11:28:18 |  5291 |  1
7320   | Track 1 |   Artist 1  |   2009-08-14 10:24:17 |  2067 |  1
```

What I want to do is is have the the duplicates add up the `hits` and `hits this week` and display as one row.

I want to fetch the mysql data as it is (with the duplicates), and then using php i wanna sum up the duplicates as one row for echo'ing.

Can someone tell me how I would go about this?

EDIT:

Heres my current sql query...

```
SELECT `files`.`file_id` , `files_meta`.`title` , `files_meta`.`artists` , `files`.`added` , `files`.`uniquehits` , `files`.`uniquehits_week` , `files_meta`.`filename`
FROM promo_artists
INNER JOIN promo_files ON promo_artists.id = promo_files.artist_id
INNER JOIN files ON files.file_id = promo_files.file_id
INNER JOIN files_meta ON files.file_id = files_meta.file_id
WHERE username = '$username' ORDER BY `files`.`added` DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do it in SQL:

```
SELECT track, artist, SUM(hits) AS hits, SUM(hits_this_week) AS hits_this_week
  FROM Atable
 GROUP BY track, artist;
```

This saves having to do the computation in PHP, and reduces the traffic between PHP and the DBMS.

Comment: From what I understand about the question, he wants to fetch the data as it is (for some reason that we ignore) : "I want to fetch the mysql data as it is (with the duplicates), and then using php"

I don't agree with this statement and your solution seems right to me, but maybe Imran could explain why he wants the data as it is ?

Comment: Yes - I'm deliberately proposing an alternative solution.  If he does want to do it in PHP, that's fine; my solution does not then apply.  I think Adam Frisby's solution might apply when tarted up a bit; I don't see how his code splits the row into bits, or handles hits vs hits this week.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
 $data[$artist][$track] += $hits;
}
```

?